# how to get response from open package in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to get the response from open() in node. URL is open in new tab and it return some response. I need that response values to go further steps I want. Is it possible to get the response, If so can any one tell me how to get the response from it. I also want to close the tab which is opened, its only possible using require('child_process').spawn or using open we can close the tab.

```
open(url, function (err) {
   if (err) 
      throw err;
   res.end()
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into setting up something like nightwatch or nemo with a selenium server that way you have access to the dom and not just a terminal open command. Or you can go headless with zombie, casper, or phantom. Or even simpler would to be to make the GET or POST directly to the url

Comment: Is there any possible way to get response from open()?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: No.

Reason: open is just a nice wrapper for the child_process.exec command. It handles dealing with different os and browsers. It passes the callback to the child_process.exec callback. The browser will not return the response to stdout unless there is some magic there that I don't know about.

References: https://github.com/pwnall/node-open/blob/master/lib/open.js and https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Solution: Setup an http connection your self in node or setup nightwatch or nemo with a selenium server that way you have access to the dom and not just a terminal open command. Or you can go headless with zombie, casper, or phantom as @jm_____ suggested.